# How to detect all model's insert or update actions on django framework?

Tags: django

i use django cache system. I want to that when anyone update or insert model, django cache clean. I think, if i get this question's answer i can do it :) also i want to advice for fix this problem. Thank you.

My Example signal;

```
from django.core.cache import cache
@receiver(post_save, sender=ModelName)
def cache_celan(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    print("anyone created something so i clean cache.")
    cache.clear()
```

This nice way but i can use it for only model. Is possible i use for it all model?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this question's answer :)
if you use "None" for sender, signals detect all model.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
@receiver(post_save, sender=None)
def cache_celan(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    print("anyone created or updated something so i clean cache.")
    cache.clear()
```